# Launch configuration first_behave.feature references non-existing project python_behave_template-master error

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-behave

I configured Pydev in eclipse and also installed behave and cucumber to run a sample project in BDD approach.

Each time i right click on the feature file (dirst_behave.feature) and Run as "Cucumber feature", i get the error -

"Launch configuration first_behave.feature references non-existing project python_behave_template-master."

I tried remapping the Python interpreter, but no luck. Any help in getting this issue resolved would be greatly appreciated.

I was using Pycharm IDE to run python scripts, but Behave approach doesn't work in Pycharm community version.(Screenshots attached for reference)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQdKc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Each time i right click on the feature file (dirst_behave.feature) and Run as "Cucumber feature", i get the error -
>
> "Launch configuration first_behave.feature references non-existing project python_behave_template-master."
>
> I was using Pycharm IDE to run python scripts, but Behave approach doesn't work in Pycharm community version.(Screenshots attached for reference)

You can't run the ***.feature** script directly from Pycharm IDE.

Try to run your script from terminal:

```
behave feature/first_behave.feature
```

Answer (score 0):

Behave works in Eclipse as well as in PyCharm (CE). But there is more handy work involved. Both IDEs allow you to run a generic command. Therefore, it should be possible to run it. This is especially needed when you need a debugger to diagnose the behave test run (but you normally need to provide your own script that imports the behave main() function same as the behave-script does).